# Is it possible to run javascript in a Vue App that is SSR in Markdown?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, server-side-rendering

I am new to VUE SSR, and I have not found a way to run javascript in response to a user select an option in a SELECT element.  My onchange event fires, but it says it can't find my javascript function.
Here is my select element:
`<select name="live" id="live" onchange="dostuff()" >`

This code is in a markdown file because the site I am trying to fix uses Netlify and Gridsome CMS.

How can I define a script so that a VUE component that has been Server Side Rendered can find that dostuff method and execute it?

Comment: Can you please update your question with some code?

Comment: StackOverflow removed the code I had.  I will try adding it again.

Comment: I believe that putting html that is going to invoke javascript doesn't work when the html is inside markdown.  The quickest way to solve the challenge is to create a new Vue page.  Sadly that increases complexity and maintenance.